# Sending array to controller in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have a div containing different images that can be sorted, i don't know how to send the `h` array containing the new ids to the controller, so that it will be updated by the controller

This is my HTML

```
<div class="row" id="lightgallery1">
if(isset($images_ext)&& !empty($images_ext))
  foreach ($images_ext as $image)
  <ul class="reorder-photos-list" ><li id="{{$image->id}}"><div style="width: auto;height: auto"><div class="img-w " id="div{{$image->id}}" style="background-image: url('{{$image->filename}}')" data-src="{{$image->filename}}">
```

```
This is my jquery code
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.reorder').on('click',function(){
            $("ul.reorder-photos-list").sortable({ tolerance: 'pointer' });
            $('.reorder').html('save reordering');
            $('.reorder').attr("id","saveReorder");
            $('#reorderHelper').slideDown('slow');
            $('.img-w').attr("data-src","");
            $('.img-w').css("cursor","move");
            $("#saveReorder").click(function( e ){
                if( !$("#saveReorder i").length ){
                    $(this).html('').prepend('saving...');
                    $("ul.reorder-photos-list").sortable('destroy');
                    $("#reorderHelper").html( "Reordering Photos - This could take a moment. Please don't navigate away from this page." );
                    var h = [];
                    $("ul.reorder-photos-list li").each(function() {  h.push($(this).attr('id') ) });

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "{{route("settings.updatephotos")}}",
                        data: {ids: " " + h + ""},
                        success: function(){
                            window.location.reload();
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                }
                e.preventDefault();    
    });
});
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `data: {ids: h}` and in your controller `request()->ids` will get you an array